# Amazon SP-Api Messaging Api problem with getting messages from buyer and seller

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I can’t find an option to receive all messages from the client and seller via sp-api via messaging API.

Is it possible to receive messages from the client using sp-api?
In Amazon's Messaging API documentation, I only see methods for sending messages, but I don't see any way to receive them.
Is it possible to get them and if so, how to do it?

Documentation link: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/messaging-api-v1-reference#operations